# How can I get texts of multiples links

Tags: r, hyperlink

I need to scrape multiples texts of links.

```
links[[1]] %>% html_nodes ('p') %>% html_text()
```

used this code for one link and it worked but I need more than just one.

```
links[[1:16]] %>% html_nodes ('p') %>% html_text()
```

I used this for scrape 16 diferents text and it didn´t work. Hopefully someoone can answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lapply` to iterate over the links :

```
library(rvest)
all_text <- lapply(links[1:16],function(x) x %>% html_nodes ('p') %>% html_text())
```